# migrate data from one MYSQL database to another

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I need to migrate some data from one MYSQL database to another but the snag is that the tables and rows are going to be different as it's going from a custom DB structure or a drupal 7 CMS.

Is there an easy way to do this or are there any tools for mapping the data to the new structure?

I have full access to both databases.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were just copying the data, you could use a standard dump, like this:

```
mysqldump -hhostname -uusername -ppassword olddbname \
 | mysql -hhostname -uusername -ppassword newdbname
```

But if you have to convert the data into something Drupal 7 compatible, you're really going to have to write some custom [`INSERT…SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)s that do the conversion.

You might want to look into Drupal's [feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), which can import data from CSV and other formats.  Feeds is officially in "alpha" at the moment, but it's still in widespread use, and if you come across a bug, it would be good to get it reported (or even fixed, if you feel you have the time to contribute to the project).

There are also various Drupal modules at drupal.org that will help you import taxonomy, users, etc from CSV or other sources.  Try something, let us know what problems you have.

Comment: Hmm, you can certainly map CSV columns to existing fields as you're importing stuff.  It's possible you will data to look at the [data module](http://drupal.org/project/data) as well, as I think it lets you use the feeds module on your existing database tables.  I haven't used either of these modules myself, but from their descriptions, they're as close as I've seen to the requirements you've listed in your question.

Comment: feeds module was the way for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using a GUI DB manager would help you??

You can try navicat: [navicat.com](http://www.navicat.com)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into exporting the file as a CSV from mysql and importing it to drupal? I am not that familiar with Drupal 7, but I believe that you can map the fields and tables that way.

Answer (score 0):

Export the actual data to a `.csv` file (or the portion of the data you want to import) and use the **Feeds** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds). It allows to map `.csv` fields into the Drupal entity fields via GUI and also allows delete and re-run imports. It's very useful.